# Maven still builds successfully with known errors

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I'm trying to run my .jar in Ubuntu, and it's failing every time with a ClassNotFoundException. I thought that my problem was with my Jar file, but after digging into it some more I am thinking that the problem is with my Maven implementation. When I run Maven it builds successfully, however there are errors in my code. I've run this same code using the same method on several different computers, and this has never happened. Maven always throws an error when appropriate, so the fact that it's allowing it to successfully build after there are clear errors makes me think that this might be the cause of my .jar problems.

I was looking in my target folder and I noticed that I'm missing the "classes", "maven-status" and "generated-sources" folders that are usually in there. My CLASSPATH variable is set to

```
"/media/client-script/java-consumer-client"
```

which should allow Maven to find my classes, since in the pom.xml it has the line

```
<start-class>com.java.consumer.client.Application</start-class>
```

which is the package for my main class. I'm not sure why but it seems like Maven is unable to find the classes in order to run.

[Here's a screenshot of my file structure.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j17lqdeojncz2y5/Screenshot%202015-10-27%2013.14.41.png?dl=0)

Does anyone have any idea why maven would not be looking in the right place for my classes? Is there an error with my Classpath setup?

Here's my pom.xml file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.java.consumer</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-consumer-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Consumer Client</name>
    <description>Sample Client for pulling streams from the Consumer Service API.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <!--
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                    -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
             <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
             <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.java.consumer.client.Application</start-class>
         <spring.boot.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.boot.websocket.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.websocket.version>        
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom file....Or where is the given snippet put into? Plugin configuration ?

Comment: @hkmarbaise I added the pom.xml file for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you must store your java classes in `src/main/java` folder. Not in `src/com/java` folder.